How can I combine/pool of the results of regression with neural network?
My study has ten imputed dependent variables (plausible values). After separately analyzing each dependent variable using a regression neural network (NN), I must combine/pool the results. I tried missing value packages (e.g., mice, Amelia ) but couldn't combine my results because the packages didn't impute the dependent variables. Also, I found the model assembled codes for classification with NN, not for regression with NN. As a result, I couldn't find the proper method and code to combine my results. How can I combine/pool my results? I would be very happy if you could help.
